# Increase zoom in Photoswipe Gallery

Tags: jquery, zooming, gallery, photoswipe

I'm using photoswipe gallery in my site, I associated the images to the gallery, now I want to increase the default zoom, but I can not find a solution, someone help me? thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use higher resolution photos instead increasing zoom. But if you still need increasing default zoom here it is.

Define these two parameters in your `options` object. Edit number `4` below as you wish

```
var options = {
    // ...
    // Your other options,
    // ...
    getDoubleTapZoom: function(isMouseClick, item) {
        if(isMouseClick) {
            return 4; //<---- This 4
        } else {
            return item.initialZoomLevel < 0.7 ? 4 : 1.33; //<---- 4 here
        }
    },
    maxSpreadZoom: 4 //<---- and this 4 here
};
```

Comment: Hey Ergec,

thanks for your promt reply. I implemented the code and it is not working on my website. Have you tried to implement it as well? Is it working?

Thanks in advance,
Manuel

Comment: @pacc88 yes I tested it then and posted my answer. It should work after you clear your cache and make sure there is no syntax error. Is it giving error or what?

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, I wasn't puting a comma, now it works. 
Do you also know how to put the click event at multiple levels? Namely: first click: 2x zoom, second click: 3x zoom, third click: 4x zoom etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how can we  attach  mouse wheel  to it and  have  4  or  5  zoom  level ?  Is it possible ?